# Simple Alarm System using Interface Java

Tags: java, interface, localtime

Okay so, I was given task to create basic alarm implementing interface.

Here's what I've got so far.

Here is my main method.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.time.LocalTime;
 
public class Monday extends Weekday{
 
    private String time;
     
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        Monday m = new Monday();
         
        String alarmer;
        System.out.print("Enter time for alarm in this format (HH:MM): " );
        alarmer = reader.nextLine();
         
        m.setAlarm(alarmer);
        m.showAlarm();
    }
 
    @Override
    public void setAlarm(String time) {
        this.time = time;
        LocalTime alarm = LocalTime.parse(time);
        LocalTime now = LocalTime.now();
         
        if (alarm.isBefore(now)) {
            System.out.println("I'll wake you up later!");
        }
         
        else {
            System.out.println("Alarm is set for tomorrow!");
        }
    }
 
    @Override
    public String showAlarm() {
        return time;
    }
     
}
```

and the next one is the interface

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.time.LocalTime;

```
interface Alarm {
         
    void setAlarm(String time);
          
    String showAlarm();
}
```

The problem here is that even though the entered input is past the current time, I always got the "I'll wake you up later". Any ideas to avoid getting the same output?

`Enter time for alarm in this format (HH:MM): 05:30`
`I'll wake you up later!`

No matter what is the input it will only always execute and display the "I'll wake you up later!" When the time entered is past the current time it should display the line of code "Alarm is set for tomorrow"

Comment: I think your logic is switched. If alarm is set as in the past (`alarm.isBefore(now)`), then display `Alarm is set for tomorrow!`

Comment: Idunno. The way I narrate it, if alarm(which is the input) is before the current time then print I'll wake you up later else which is after or past the current tine. But the problem is the same all over no matter the input is

Comment: you may also need to show how the input is provided to the program, i.e. sample input format

Comment: As a side note, your `setAlarm` should generally take the time as a time of some sort; converting to and from a String is a separate responsibility.

Comment: What do you mean by separate? Can you please enlighten me more, still confuse on what to do next here.

Comment: can you add `System.out.println(alarm + " vs " + now);` right below this line `LocalTime now = LocalTime.now();`, so that we can see the value.

Comment: @Agus Here's what I've got, `05:30 vs 16:39:44.893505`

Comment: By "separate", chrylis likely meant [*Separation of concerns*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). The part of the program that sets the alarm should not be responsible for parsing and validating the user's input. Those are two different kinds of work. Just like different jobs should be held by different people/experts, so should each part of your program specialize in a very narrow duty. So `setAlarm(String time)` should be `setAlarm(LocalTime time)` with the input parsing performed before that call.

Comment: and what is the message displayed ? if it is `I'll wake you up later!` then your program is already correct right @Hannacookielucylovemilkang

Comment: @Agus, shouldn't it be `Alarm is set for tomorrow!` because It's already past the current time?

Comment: @Hannacookielucylovemilkang If now is 5 PM and you set alarm for 10 PM, the alarm will fire *today*. If now is 5 PM and you set alarm for 3 PM, the alarm will fire *tomorrow*. Going past midnight means you will have moved into a new day. So any time-of-day earlier than now means *tomorrow*.

Comment: @BasilBourque, Regardless of the input it always says `I'll wake you up later` even though I input `4:30PM`, and it is already `5PM` in here.

Comment: I think the expected outcome of the code is not as what is written in the logic @Hannacookielucylovemilkang. Using `if (alarm.isBefore(now))`, if alarm is before now (which is the case if alarm is `05:30` and now is `16:39`), then `I'll wake you up later!` will be displayed. So that is actually an expected result as it only compares hour & minute, not including the date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the Question and Comments, you seem to be confused about the logic of a 24-hour clock without the context of dates.

- If now is 5 PM  and you set alarm for 10 PM , the alarm will fire today. All the moments with a time-of-day between the current time-of-day and midnight will be today.
- If now is 5 PM  and you set alarm for 3 PM , the alarm will fire tomorrow. Any future moment with a time-of-day before the current time-of-day will happen after midnight, so tomorrow.

Going past midnight means you will have moved into a new day. So any time-of-day earlier than now means tomorrow.

Here is some simple example code.

Simulate a current time-of-day of 5 PM.

```java
// ----------|  now = 17:00 |------------------------------
LocalTime now = LocalTime.of( 17 , 0 );
System.out.println( "now = " + now );
```

Set alarm at various time-of-day values: 22:00, 15:00, and 05:30.

```java
// ----------|  alarm 22:00  |------------------------------
LocalTime tenPM = LocalTime.parse( "22:00" );
System.out.println( "" );
System.out.println( "tenPM = " + tenPM );
if ( tenPM.isBefore( now ) )
{
    System.out.println( "I'll wake you up tomorrow." );
} else
{
    System.out.println( "Alarm is set for today." );
}

// ----------|  alarm 15:00  |------------------------------
LocalTime threePM = LocalTime.parse( "15:00" );
System.out.println( "" );
System.out.println( "threePM = " + threePM );
if ( threePM.isBefore( now ) )
{
    System.out.println( "I'll wake you up tomorrow." );
} else
{
    System.out.println( "Alarm is set for today." );
}

// ----------|  alarm 05:30  |------------------------------
LocalTime fiveThirtyInMorning = LocalTime.parse( "05:30" );
System.out.println( "" );
System.out.println( "fiveThirtyInMorning = " + fiveThirtyInMorning );
if ( threePM.isBefore( now ) )
{
    System.out.println( "I'll wake you up tomorrow." );
} else
{
    System.out.println( "Alarm is set for today." );
}
```

When run:

```
now = 17:00

tenPM = 22:00
Alarm is set for today.

threePM = 15:00
I'll wake you up tomorrow.

fiveThirtyInMorning = 05:30
I'll wake you up tomorrow.
```

## Time-of-day, not a moment

Your alarm is **not tracking a moment**, a specific point on the timeline. That would involve the `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, or `ZonedDateTime` classes.

Your alarm is tracking a time-of-day without the context of a date and without the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC. So your alarm uses [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html) class.

Comment: You know what, the time in here right now is 5:15PM which is equivalent to 17:15. So, here is the problem I tried to input 05:30 which would become 05:30AM right?, so the problem is it keeps giving me `I'll wake you up later` even though it should be `Alarm is set for tomorrow`

Comment: @Hannacookielucylovemilkang Compare your `if` statement to mine. And see the third case I added to my code, to show your 05:30 example.

Comment: Ow, now I get it. I think the problem is I wrongly made use of the `isBefore` and `isAfter` So, tried to input `20:00` and the time here is `17:00` it gives me `Alarm is set for tomorrow` even though it should be `I'll wake you up later`

Comment: Great answer! In my view, the last paragraph of the answer (**Time-of-day, not a moment**) is the most important part of this answer. For more examples of `LocalTime`, one can refer [this Oracle's tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/datetime.html). And, when it comes to creativity, no one can beat @BasilBourque. Salute to his art of crafting an answer!